# search table with insensitive value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
    {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
            .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
$(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup",function() {
        if (this.value != "") {
            $("#body tr").hide();
            $("#body tr:containsi('" + this.value + "')").show();
        } else {
            $('.table_elements').each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        }
        completeSearch();
    });
});
```

This works fine however it has a small bug.

it is case sensitive.

i searched stackoverflow and found the following function:

```
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
    {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
            .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

however when i debug it using firebug it doesnt seem to go into the function

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the new function?   Which line of code?  It appears to be called containsi, not just contains?

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: @Miro please add your answer again it works now my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this somewhere?  How are you calling the custom extension?

```
$("#body tr:containsi('" + this.value + "')").show();
```

And yes, seems to work so far here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7kxp/